# Are photos still saved on Mac with PhotoStream after deleted on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, photos.app, photo-stream

Been using PhotoStream for years and still don't fully understand it...When I take pics on my iPhone, they show up on my MBP in Photos, via PhotoStream. If I delete them from the iPhone will they still remain on MacBook or other devices? Or do I need to download them into Photos and off the phone to be sure they are saved?

I am confused by this and just want to delete from iPhone to free up space. Is this automatically done for me every time or do I need certain settings on/off to have this occur? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

if you want them to be safe for sure, just drag them into a new folder. but i dont thing it will erase them, because they are stored in icloud, and when you stop them on the iphone, it asks if you want to delete them, and i would imagine it would also ask on your MBP if you decided to stop syncing them. so to be clear, dont delete them by hand on your phone. go to icloud, where it lets you pick what to sync, and turn off photostream. it will ask if you want to keep photos on your device or delete them. it will delete on your phone but not in icloud. case in point, i just reset and deleted everything on my phone to get ready to sell, and all of my photostream pics are still in tact on my MBP. so that would make sense.

Comment: PhotoStream will NOT let me drag photos anywhere, unfortunately